# JS disappearing property

Tags: javascript, object, properties, undefined

```
/*jslint browser: true, devel: true */
//*********************** Constants **************************
var FPS = 30;

var ANIMATIONOBJECTX = 1;
var ANIMATIONOBJECTY = 2;
var ANIMATIONOBJECTOPACITY = 3;
var ANIMATIONOBJECTWIDTH = 4;
var ANIMATIONOBJECTHEIGHT = 5;
var ANIMATIONOBJECTROTATION = 6;

//*********************** Rotation **************************

function setRotation(view, angle) {
    "use strict";
    view.css({
        "-webkit-transform" : "rotate(" + angle + "deg)",
        "-moz-transform" : "rotate(" + angle + "deg)",
        "-ms-transform" : "rotate(" + angle + "deg)",
        "-o-transform" : "rotate(" + angle + "deg)",
        "transform" : "rotate(" + angle + "deg)"
    });

    view.angle = angle; //For getting the angle later
}

//*********************** Classes **************************

var AnimationObject = function (start, end, time, isSmooth, type, object) {
    "use strict";
    this.type = type;
    this.stages = [];

    var dif = end - start,
        a,
        b,
        steps = time * FPS;

    if (isSmooth) {
        for (a = 0; a < steps; a += 1) {
            if (a <= steps / 2) {
                //Normal parabola
                b = (2.0 / 9) * Math.pow(a, 2) * Math.pow(1.0 / time, 2);
            } else {
                //Upside down parabola
                b = (-2.0 / 9) * Math.pow(a - (FPS * time), 2) * Math.pow(1.0 / time, 2) + 100;
            }

            this.stages.push(b / 100 * dif + start);
        }
    } else {
        for (a = 0; a < steps; a += 1) {
            this.stages.push(a / steps * dif + start);
        }
    }

    //Applies animation value differently depending on type
    if (type === ANIMATIONOBJECTX) {
        this.applyAnimation = function (step) {
            object.css("left", this.stages[step]);
        };
    } else if (type === ANIMATIONOBJECTY) {
        this.applyAnimation = function (step) {
            object.css("top", this.stages[step]);
        };
    } else if (type === ANIMATIONOBJECTOPACITY) {
        this.applyAnimation = function (step) {
            object.css("opacity", this.stages[step]);
        };
    } else if (type === ANIMATIONOBJECTWIDTH) {
        this.applyAnimation = function (step) {
            object.css("width", this.stages[step]);
        };
    } else if (type === ANIMATIONOBJECTHEIGHT) {
        this.applyAnimation = function (step) {
            object.css("height", this.stages[step]);
        };
    } else if (type === ANIMATIONOBJECTROTATION) {
        this.applyAnimation = function (step) {
            setRotation(object, this.stages[step]);
        };
    }
};

var AnimationManager = function (time, completionMethod) {
    "use strict";
    this.animationObjects = [];
    this.time = time;
    this.add = function (animationObject) {
        this.animationObjects.push(animationObject);
    };
    this.completionMethod = completionMethod;
    this.currentStage = 0;
    this.maximumStage = this.time * FPS;

    this.tick = function () {
        this.currentStage += 1;
        if (this.currentStage < this.maximumStage) {
            setTimeout(this.tick.bind(this), 1000.0 / FPS);
        } else {
            //Set manager to nil in the completion method
            this.completionMethod();
        }

        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < this.animationObjects.length; i += 1) {
            this.animationObjects[i].applyAnimation(this.currentStage);

        }
    };

    //Call this to start
    this.startAnimation = function () {
        this.timer = setTimeout(this.tick.bind(this), 1000.0 / FPS);
    };
};

//*********************** Animate Objects **************************
function animatePosition(object, manager, x, y, smooth) {
    "use strict";
    var curX = parseFloat(object.position().left),
        curY = parseFloat(object.position().top);

    manager.add(
        new AnimationObject(curX, x, manager.time, smooth, ANIMATIONOBJECTX, object)
    );
    manager.add(
        new AnimationObject(curY, y, manager.time, smooth, ANIMATIONOBJECTY, object)
    );
}

function animateSize(object, manager, w, h, smooth) {
    "use strict";
    var curW = parseFloat(object.css("width")),
        curH = parseFloat(object.css("height"));

    manager.add(
        new AnimationObject(curW, w, manager.time, smooth, ANIMATIONOBJECTWIDTH, object)
    );
    manager.add(
        new AnimationObject(curH, h, manager.time, smooth, ANIMATIONOBJECTHEIGHT, object)
    );
}

function animateOpacity(object, manager, opacity) {
    "use strict";
    var curO = parseFloat(object.css("opacity"));

    manager.add(
        new AnimationObject(curO, opacity, manager.time, false, ANIMATIONOBJECTOPACITY, object)
    );
}

function animateRotation(object, manager, angle, smooth) {
    "use strict";
    console.log(object.angle);
    if (object.angle === undefined) {
        object.angle = 0;
    }

    manager.add(
        new AnimationObject(object.angle, angle, manager.time, smooth, ANIMATIONOBJECTROTATION, object)
    );
}

var view;
function doSomething() {
    "use strict";
    view = $("#test");
    var manager;
    view.html("animating");

    var complete = function () {
        view.html("complete"); 
        manager = null;
        setTimeout(doSomething, 100);
    };

    manager = new AnimationManager(Math.random() * 1.0, complete);
    animatePosition(view, manager, Math.random() * 400, Math.random() * 500, true);
    animateOpacity(view, manager, Math.random());
    animateSize(view, manager, Math.random() * 500, Math.random() * 500, true);
    animateRotation(view, manager, Math.random() * 360, Math.round(Math.random()));
    manager.startAnimation();
}
```

That doSomething method at the bottom runs when I press a button. The animateRotation method detects that the object.angle is undefined and sets it to 0. During the animation, the setRotation is called and sets the object.angle to it's angle (and i can console.log it fine too). But when the complete function is called and the animation starts again, the object(view in the doSomething method).angle is reset back to undefined again. What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is right now, `view = $("#test");` runs everytime `doSomething` is called, which selects the same DOM node, but returns a different jQuery object everytime.

The easiest way of fixing this would be to do the following:

```
view = view || $("#test");
```

However you should probably refactor your code so that it doesn't rely on a global variable.

Once you will fix this, you will notice that an `angle` property will exist on the object, but it will still be undefined at the end of the animation. That's because the last time `setRotation` is called, `angle` is also `undefined`.

Comment: ah thank you. it was undefined last because the loop repeats one more time than the length of the array so i added a -1.

Comment: Why not use a global variable? And how